# JKS file information for Android is published on Google Play Store or public

Tags: android, flutter, jks

I am about to create .apk or .aab file for the Android release.
I just created JKS file for the release. And I had to input some of my own information. For example,

```
first and last name
the name of your organizational unit
the name of your organization
...
```

I worry that this information is published on Google Play Store or public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information is only used to create the key and will not be published. You should also keep the key private, because it is used to identify you when you are trying to update your app.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. Do you know where there is the information?

Comment: You can read more here: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing